# Unity Annoying NDK issue

Tags: android, unity3d

I have a very annoying issue with unity 2022.2.0b1, I have tried both NDK R23C and R25, none of them work.

NDK 23.2.8568313 detected. Unity requires NDK r23b (23.1.17779620).

Where can i get NDK r23b (23.1.17779620)? the NDK website https://github.com/android/ndk/wiki/Unsupported-Downloads only has 1 of the r23, and that's 23c.

Comment: Can you not change the required version of the ANDK by editing the project source?    You can download the file [here](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r23b-windows.zip).  The file still exists in the repository it isn't listed.

Comment: **While you can install that specific version you really should just update the project.**

Comment: That version worked, thank you! But, how do i update the project? i have no clue to be honest of how the NDK works and that stuff, all i care about is that my game actually get's built.

Comment: You haven’t even told us anything about the project your attempting to compile (you shouldn’t in this question since that’s a SO question). How you change the target version seems straightforward to me